# How to use TrueZip to compress files?

Tags: java, truezip

I have a file, let's say `C:\source.dat`. I want to compress it into a zip file `C:\folder\destination.zip`.

I can't find a straightforward example, and the HelloWorld provided with the Maven project doesn't really apply in my case because I'm not writing a plaintext file, so hopefully someone can enlighten me on this.

For reference, the code provided in the example:

```
@Override
protected int work(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // By default, ZIP files use character set IBM437 to encode entry names
    // whereas JAR files use UTF-8.
    // This can be changed by configuring the respective archive driver,
    // see Javadoc for TApplication.setup().
    final Writer writer = new TFileWriter(
            new TFile("archive.zip/dir/HälloWörld.txt"));
    try {
        writer.write("Hello world!\n");
    } finally {
        writer.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"project doesn't really apply in my case (not a text file)"*  So what?  Did you actually *try* the example with a text file?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Yes, but because HelloWorld uses a Writer to write text directly into the entry. In my case, because I'm not working with text files, I obviously can't do the same.

Comment: It would have been handy to mention that information (in the question) since we are not psychic..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's as simple as this:

```
new TFile("source.dat").cp(new TFile("destination.zip/source.dat"));
```

For more information, please refer to the Javadoc for the TFile class at http://truezip.java.net/apidocs/de/schlichtherle/truezip/file/TFile.html .

You may also want to try the TrueZIP Archetype File*, which is introduced at http://truezip.java.net/kick-start/index.html . The archetype generates many sample programs which you should explore to get a feel for the API.

Comment: The links are broken now. =(

Answer (score 1):

This is a straight forward thing to do.

Use

1.**ZipOutputStream** -- This Class of java This class implements an output stream filter for writing files in the ZIP file format. Includes support for both compressed and uncompressed entries.

**Offical Docs**

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html

2.**ZipEntry** -- This This class is used to represent a ZIP file entry.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class ConverToZip {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Take a buffer
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        try {

            // Create object of FileOutputStream

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\folder\\destination.zip.");

            // Get ZipOutstreamObject Object
            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);


            ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry("source.dat");
            zos.putNextEntry(ze);
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:\\source.dat");

            int len;
            while ((len = in .read(buffer)) > 0) {
                zos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }

            in .close();
            zos.closeEntry();

            //remember close it
            zos.close();

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm actually referring to TrueZip here, but thanks for your answer anyway!

Comment: @ohseekay Ohhh Sorry then I missed it. Anyways I dont know much about truezip.